# Equation array troubles

Tags: equations

I have a problem and I've been searching forever for a fix to it.

I have three equation arrays that are huge. They all have about 10 to 20 equations.

LaTeX does not seem to want to split up the equation arrays onto different pages.  A consequences of this is that I have huge black vertical spaces separating the equation arrays just so every array is one just one piece of paper. How do I get rid of these black, empty, vertical spaces?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you're using `eqnarray`, then don't. See [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln).

Comment: Are you using the `eqnarray` or the `align` environment? Please advise. If it's the latter, you could use the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` to allow page breaks after explicit line breaks. If you're using `eqnarray`: Don't do it...

Comment: To expand on what @Werner said, look at the documentation for the amsmath package, section 3.9: “Vertical spacing and page breaks in multiline displays”.

Comment: *black* vertical spaces?  this sounds like the equations are too wide as well as too many of them.  a "minimal" example (although possibly not too minimal in this case, so let's try "typical") would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on my computer, but I think you'll use the

```
\begin{align*} 
eqn  1 &= equation 1 \\
eqn 2 &= equation 2 \\
\end{align*}
```

you could then use `\tag{no}` to manually no. them. You'll need `\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}` though. it should automatically break to a new page. hope it helps ... = should be replaced by you symbol.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't add to a possible solution. Since a MWE (or any information at all) is missing, this is just guesswork.